# Как исправить ошибку центра обновления Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Уже давненько открывая Центр обновления виндоус видел надпись: "Что-то пошло не так. Попытайтесь повторно открыть параметры позже".

После гугления как исправить эту ошибку: [image: скриншот]

Виндоус лицензионный. Активирован.
**Как исправить?**

Comment: Давно? Тогда скачать и запустить Windows Upgrade wizard. И более не заниматься "оптимизациями" с отключением "ненужных служб" и запусками маловменяемых "оптимизаторов" по левым гайдам.

Comment: Можно ещё грохнуть `SoftwareDistribution` и запустить поиск обнов заново.

Comment: @Akina При его запуске вылетает ошибка: "Не удается найти необходимый файл..."

Comment: @donRumata Как и где?

Comment: *При его запуске вылетает ошибка: "Не удается найти необходимый файл..."* Upgrade wizard самодостаточен. Он должен был распаковать себя в папку C:\Windows10Upgrade и запустить Windows10UpgraderApp.exe. Это всё - есть?

Comment: @Akina есть. Но он не запускается(
Пишет, что не удается найти файл C\Windows10Upgrade\Windows10UpgraderApp.exe
Хотя он находится по этому же адресу.

Comment: Откройте загруженный файл (надеюсь, с сайта Microsoft загружен?) как архив и сверьте содержимое и то, что распаковалось в каталог.

Comment: @Akina Да. Да, в распакованной папке даже немного больше файлов. И пару папок есть.

Comment: Тогда либо какой-то твикер перестарался, либо имеется серьёзное повреждение файлов ОС, либо вирусочек... *Да, в распакованной папке даже немного больше файлов. И пару папок есть.* Это нормально. Некоторые файлы создаются в процессе работы.

Comment: Так что же делать?

Comment: Я бы предложил сделать бэкап критичной информации и запустить процедуру восстановления с установочного носителя.

Comment: @Akina Нашел Trojan:Win32/Ymacco.AAAA

Comment: Ну если троян, то смысл сидеть на этой ОС не вижу никакого. Сохраняй файло на отдельный винт, всё сноси и ставь заново.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка явно вызвана повреждением системных файлов. Для устранения ошибки, рекомендую выполнить три шага:

1. провести полное сканирование системы Защитником Windows;
2. в командной строке от имени администратора выполнить команду (должен быть интернет):

> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

будет выполнено восстановление образа системы (если был поврежден):

> PS C:\Windows\system32> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
>
> Cистема DISM Версия: 10.0.19041.844
>
> Версия образа: 10.0.19042.906
>
> [==========================100.0%==========================]
> Восстановление выполнено успешно. Операция успешно завершена.

3. далее выполнить команду:

> sfc /scannow

будут выполнены проверка системных файлов и их восстановление:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> sfc /scannow
>
> Начато сканирование системы.  Этот процесс может занять некоторое
> время.
>
> Начало стадии проверки при сканировании системы.
> Проверка 100% завершена.
>
> Программа защиты ресурсов Windows обнаружила поврежденные файлы и успешно
> их восстановила.

Comment: Никаких ошибок не обнаружено. Проблема осталась.